# debug the jquery dataTable server side :ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, datatables, serverside-datatable

To implement jquery Datatable server-side processing by following the sample from this  repository https://github.com/DavidSuescunPelegay/jQuery-datatable-server-side-net-core

The controller for loading result is defined like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadTable([FromBody]DtParameters dtParameters)
    {

        return Json(new DtResult<TestRegister>
        {
            Draw = dtParameters.Draw,
            RecordsTotal = totalResultsCount,
            RecordsFiltered = filteredResultsCount,
            Data = await result
                .Skip(dtParameters.Start)
                .Take(dtParameters.Length)
                .ToListAsync()
        });
    }
```

TestRegister, DtResult classes is copied as from repository

```
    https://github.com/DavidSuescunPelegay/jQuery-datatable-server-side-net-core/blob/master/src/jQueryDatatableServerSideNetCore/Models/DatabaseModels/TestRegister.cs
    
    https://github.com/DavidSuescunPelegay/jQuery-datatable-server-side-net-core/blob/master/src/jQueryDatatableServerSideNetCore/Models/AuxiliaryModels/DatatableModels.cs
```

The code seems to be working fine and  i am getting response back at HTML page  as expected

I changed the class to my own custom class StudentMaster , which is  representation of an entity framework Db table and it have some properties and related tables like

```
    public class StudentMaster
    {
        public StudentMaster();
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        ...
        ..
        ...
        ...
        ..
        
        public StudentType SType { get; set; }
        ...
        ..
        ...
        public ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
        
    }
```

From controller now i am returning this class and there is no exceptions and debugger is striking return Json line

```
       var query = // my actual sql query to fetch data from db table with all conditions 
       
        var response = new DtResult<AppEntities.StudentMaster>
        {
            Draw = dtParams.Draw,
            RecordsTotal = totalResultsCount,
            RecordsFiltered = filteredResultsCount,
            Data = query
               .Skip(dtParams.Start)
               .Take(dtParams.Length)
               .ToListAsync()
        };
        try
        {
            return Json(response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("NOK");
        }
```

But i am not getting any response back in HTML instead  at console i can see this error  and no exceptions is hit by debugger. I can see debugger is passing line of return Json

VM71:1 POST https://localhost:44320/Students/LoadTable net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

And the debugger is coming till the line of DtResult class, then there is no progress with debugging and  i can see the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message in the browser console

```
  public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to debug the reason for this error, to know what is happening at this line and why debugger is not moving further . Is it because of some error with properties or
is it because of error with type of data i am passing (which is a list of object) or something else?

I tried to replace the data with custom defined list of items  with just 2 properties for the same class like below and there is no issues

```
        List<AppEntities.StudentMaster> fakeItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => new AppEntities.StudentMaster
        {
            Name = "Name " + i,
            identifier = "identifier" + i                
        }).ToList();
```

So it looks like something with the data is causing troubles , but not sure how to debug this

Answer (score -1):

apply "debugger" where you want to debug the jquery. And then upload it to server and then you can debug easily.
For eaxample below:

```
function func(){
    //Some stuff
    debugger;  //Debugging is automatically started from here
    //Some stuff
}
func();
```

Comment: error is not at Javascript side, Its some issues at backend only